# Add content in between of foreach

Tags: customization, query

I have the following foreach witch gets all the content in several groups. I am using Magic Fields.

```
 <?php $omtaleseksjoner = get_group('Seksjoner');
foreach($omtaleseksjoner as $seksjoner){ 
    echo "<h3>" . $seksjoner['sectiontitle'][1] . "</h3>";
    echo $seksjoner['sectioncontent'][1];
} 
?>
```

I have usually 5 groups in this foreach, and I want to break it off in two places.

Is it possible to insert other content e.g. after group 2 and 4 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep tracks of number of cycles and run extras when counter matches. Something like this:

```
$array  = array(1,2,3,4,5);

$i = 0;

foreach($array as $set) {

    if(2 == $i)
        echo 'after 2';

    if(4 == $i)
        echo 'after 4';

    echo $set;

    $i++;
}
```

I must note that this is more of PHP basics and really has nothing to do with WordPress. I highly recommend [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/) as first stop for such.